# Not able to get exact value for chinese characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a column which has some Chinese characters as its value. When I compare its value with BLANK, it returns true.

When I convert its value to VARCHAR, it returns "????". When I convert its value to NVARCHAR, it again returns BLANK.

How can I get exact value of the column and use it as I want?

Comment: What is the collation for the column and table?

Comment: Both's collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI

Comment: @KapilKothari, what is the column data type?

Comment: Column has a data type of NVARCHAR

Answer (score 0):

How are you inserting the Chinese text?

If you use -

```
INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable(NVarcharColumn)
VALUES('Chinese stuff')
```

then SQL will convert the text into VARCHAR and unicode characters will be lost.

On the other hand, if you use-

```
INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable(NVarcharColumn)
VALUES(N'Chinese stuff')
```

then the column would have the text that you require.

Comment: Insertion logic cannot be changed in our case. The values to be inserted into a column will be a normal text with Chinese characters. Please suggest other logic?

Comment: Can you get back the original decimal number after truncating it? No.